# What is the difference between scope of these two functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am sorry if this is too naive, just got stuck with this while trying to answer another question. :) Here in the code below both `bar.x` and `bar.y` has similar/same function body (does it matter where the function is initially declared?). And I guess that the scope of a `foo` is lost when it is assigned to `y`, but still when I call `bar.y()` why is it not taking the `global_var` inside its closure? Is there a way both `x` and `y` can output `300`?

```js
global_var = 2
var foo = function(){
  console.log("y", global_var)
}
var bar = (function b(){
  var global_var = 300;
  var x = function(){
    console.log("x",global_var);
  };
  var y = foo;
  return {x: x, y: y};
})();

bar.x(); //300
bar.y(); //2
setTimeout(bar.x); //300
setTimeout(bar.y); //2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it matter where the function is initially declared

Yes. The scope of a function is determined solely by where it is declared.

> And I guess that the scope of a foo is lost when it is assigned to  y

No. The scope is unchanged.

> when I call bar.y() why is it not taking the global_var inside its closure?

Because the scope of a function is determined solely by where it is **declared**.

> Is there a way both x and y can output 300?

Not by twiddling with scope.

You'd have to rewrite the function to get the data from somewhere else, e.g. from object properties.

```js
var global_object = {};
global_object.data = 1;

global_object.foo = function() {
  console.log("y", this.data);
};

var bar = (function b() {
  var local_object = {};
  local_object.data = 2;
  local_object.x = function() {
    console.log("x", this.data);
  };
  local_object.y = global_object.foo;
  return local_object;
})();

bar.x(); // 2
bar.y(); // 2
setTimeout(bar.x.bind(bar)); // 2
setTimeout(bar.y.bind(bar)); // 2
```

Comment: My concepts of `this` and lexical scope got mixed up I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closure involved in assigning `foo` to `y`. The function `foo`'s scope is determined where is is defined, which is at the top of your code sample, and the `global_var` inside the body of that function will always refer to the `global_var` variable that is (implicitly) defined in line 1, and not any other variable with the same name.

Assigning `foo` to `y` has no effect on the scope of that function. All that assignment accomplishes is that it makes `foo` accessible from a new variable.

> Is there a way both x and y can output 300?

Not when the function is defined like that, but you could have something similar to what you're expecting if you use `this`:

```js
global_var = 2

var foo = function(){
  console.log("y", this.global_var)
}

var bar = (function b(){
  var global_var = 300;

  var x = function(){
    console.log("x", this.global_var);
  };

  var y = foo;

  return {x: x, y: y, global_var: global_var};
})();

foo();                       // 2

bar.x();                     // 300
bar.y();                     // 300

setTimeout(bar.x);           // 2
setTimeout(bar.y);           // 2

setTimeout(bar.x.bind(bar)); // 300
setTimeout(bar.y.bind(bar)); // 300
```

Comment: I was trying to change lexical scope just like how we bind `this`. Now I understand where I went wrong.